# Why are there only two irreducible representations in the C3 group?

Tags: group-theory

There are three elements in a [$C_3$ group](http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=203&option=4) and there are three classes in this group cause it is an Abelian group.

\begin{array}{c|ccc|cc}
\hline
C_3 & E & C_3 & C_3^2 & & \varepsilon = \exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}/3) \\ \hline
\mathrm{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & z, R_z & x^2+y^2, z^2 \\
\mathrm{E} & \left\{ \begin{aligned}1 \\ 1\end{aligned} \right. & \begin{aligned}\varepsilon \\ \varepsilon^* \end{aligned} & \left. \begin{aligned}\varepsilon^* \\ \varepsilon \end{aligned}\right\} & (x, y), (R_x, R_y) & (x^2-y^2,xy), (xz, yz) \\ \hline
\end{array}

According to group representation theory, the number of classes of a group should be the same as the number of irreducible representations of the group, which means there should be 3 irreducible representations for $C_3$ group.

In a character table, this means there should be 3 rows.

Further more, according to $$\sum_{i}l_{j}^2= h$$
in which $l_{j}$ stands for the dimension of the $j-th$ irreducible representation, and $h$ stands for the order of the group.

All of the three irreducible representation of $C_3$ group should be of 1 dimension.

But in the link above, for $C_3$ group, there are only two irreducible representations, and one of the irreducible representation is of 2 dimension, so it seems it violates the basic results of group representation theory.

So, what I have misunderstood?

Comment: http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=203&option=4 The E representation is two very similar representations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You got everything right. It is just that two of these representations would use **complex numbers** ($\varepsilon=e^{2\pi i\over3}$ and $\varepsilon^2$), and we don't like that, so we stick them together into one representation of dimension 2, which makes the imaginary part vanish. Afterwards we treat this representation as "*kinda irreducible*". In fact it can be reduced, but we just don't want to go that way.

The same applies to other cyclic groups.

Comment: Thank you! So actually the representation labeled $E$ in the character table is actually a reducible representation? I observe that the inner product $1+\epsilon \epsilon^* +\epsilon^*\epsilon =3 $.

Comment: Well, let's put it this way: it is reducible if you allow complex numbers, and irreducible otherwise.